# GWT RPC mechanism how to use non void return type

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have a scenario wherein I need to specify a return type to the Synchrnous function, the code is as follows :

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("show_box")
public interface ShowBoxCommandService extends RemoteService{

 public ArrayList<String> showBox();

}
```

The implementation of the method on the server is :

```
public ArrayList<String> showBox() {

  ArrayList<String> box = new ArrayList<String>();
  Iterator<Box> boxes = BoxRegistry.getInstance().getBoxes();
  while (boxes.hasNext()) {
     box.add(boxes.next().toString());
  }
  return box;
}
```

I am trying to define the callback variable in the following format at the client side in order to call the method

```
 AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
           public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
              // TODO: Do something with errors.
              // console was not started properly
           }

           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Void result) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // dialog saying that the console is started succesfully

           }
        };
```

update with the aync interface code :

```
    public interface ShowBoxCommandServiceAsync {

   void showBox(AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>> callback);

  }
```

But this is causing the definition of the method in the Async method to change.

Any ideas or clues will be helpful.

Thanks,
Bhavya

P.S. Apologies if this is a repetition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback should be:

```
AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {
       public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
          // TODO: Do something with errors.
          // console was not started properly
       }

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // dialog saying that the console is started succesfully

       }
    };
```

If you don't need to utilize the result then you can ignore it, but if that is the case, you should probably question your design and why you would need the method to return an `ArrayList<String>` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If the service interface looks like this:

```
public interface ShowBoxCommandService extends RemoteService {
  public ArrayList<String> showBox();
}
```

then you must have an associated async interface:

```
public interface ShowBoxCommandServiceAsync {
  public void showBox(AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>> callback);
}
```

Which means, that the type of the callback that you should pass to `showBox` is `AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>`.

```
new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> list) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @lonut when use the above case to call the show box method , I get an error in the IDE asking me to change the return type of the async interface to ArrayList<String>, I do remember reading that the async interace should have a return type of void

Comment: @Bhavya PH, can you update the question with the source code of the async interface? The IDE shouldn't complain if the return type is void. By the way, what IDE? Eclipse with Google's plugin?

Comment: @lonut thank you very much for your comments I have updated the question with the code

Comment: @Bhavya PH, I have no idea. Everything looks okay. Maybe it's a problem with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? Your method returns an ArrayList and you are declaring void in your call?

```
Change <Void> to <ArrayList<String>>
```

Comment: if i dont use void the return type of the aync call is changed from void to ArrayList which should not be the case, any clues on this ?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't understand what you are talking about. If you want the String list, return that, if you want to return void, dont return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback should not be Void. If your synchronous method returns a List of Strings, the async callback method should receive the List. You'll have to use the ArrayList, because the class needs to implement the Serializable interface.

```
AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {
   public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      // TODO: Do something with errors.
      // console was not started properly
   }

   @Override
   public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // dialog saying that the console is started succesfully
   }
};
```

Comment: The method will return an ArrayList<String> and not ArrayList<Box>